# RBG values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

Sorry if this is REALLY bad, i'm new at python so please excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to create a method which can take a word as a parameter and return that word with HTML font tags with rainbow colors.

```
def rainbow(word):
    length = len(word)
    #set rgb values
    r = 255 #rgb value set to red by default
    g = 0
    b = 0
    sub = int(765/length)
    counter = 0
    string = ""
    for x in range(0, length):
        letter = word[counter]
        s = "<font color = #%02X%02X%02X>%s</font>" % (r, g, b, letter)
        string = string+s
        counter+=1
        if (r == 255) and (g >= 0) and (b == 0): 
            g = g+sub
            if g > 255: g = 255
        if (r > 0) and (g == 255) and (b == 0):
            r = r-sub
            if r<0: r = 0
        if (r == 0) and (g == 255) and (b == 0): #b is not increasing
            b = b+sub
            if b>255: b = 255
        if (r == 0) and (g > 0) and (b == 255): #this one doesn't work either
            g = g-sub
            if g<0: g = 0
        if (r <255) and (g == 0) and (b == 255): #or this one
            r = r+sub
            if r>255: r = 255
return string
```

Yeah I know it's pretty bad, like I said, i'm new. However, when this script is executed, the 'b' value is never increased. So the output always returns a correct rainbow up to the green color. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: Have you tried any print statements to see what is happening?

Comment: What does the constant 765 represent?

Comment: The constant 765 represents the 3 255 values for r g & b (I was just playing around with it and it worked)

Comment: Is there not a satisfactory answer? If there is, can you accept the best one? (that would be JF's)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to get rainbow colors using [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Then [`colorsys.hsv_to_rgb()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html) allows to convert from HSV to RGB:

```
import html
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb

def html_rainbow(text):
    n = len(text)
    L = []
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        hue = i / n
        r, g, b = [int(f*255 + .5) for f in hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)]
        L.append('<font color=#%02X%02X%02X>%s</font>' % (
            r, g, b, html.escape(c, quote=False)))
    return ''.join(L)
```

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: %(prog)s <text>"""
import sys
import tempfile
import time
import webbrowser

def open_in_browser(html):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", suffix='.html') as file:
        file.write(html)
        file.flush()
        webbrowser.open(file.name)
        time.sleep(60) # give the browser a minute to open before
                       # deleting the file

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__ % dict(prog=sys.argv[0]))
open_in_browser(html_rainbow(sys.argv[1]))
```

Example:

```
$ python3 html_rainbow.py "rainbow & rainbow"
```

[image: rainbow]

Comment: This answer is much better than mine. I still like the sine wave but points to you for switching to HSV; I didn't realize this was in the Python standard library. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do precisely, but that block of conditionals seemed awfully inelegant, so I skipped it and wrote this solution:

```
def rainbow(word):
    import math
    wordLen = len(word)
    freq = (2 * math.pi) / wordLen
    amplitude = 255 / 2
    center = 255 / 2
    line = ''
    for i in range(wordLen):
        currChar = word[i]
        #G and B should be shifted to all three channels are not the same color
        gShift = math.pi * 2 / 3
        bShift = math.pi * 4 / 3
        r = math.sin(freq * i) * amplitude + center
        g = math.sin(freq * i + gShift) * amplitude + center
        b = math.sin(freq * i + bShift) * amplitude + center
        line += '<font color="rgb({},{},{})">{}</font>'.format(r, g, b, currChar)
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print rainbow('pooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooop')
```

This uses a sine wave¹ to produce undulating values between 0 and 255 for each channel before printing the tags with each character.

This is unrelated, but also notice that I used the string format() method instead of the deprecated method you were using in your code.

One more protip: avoid naming a variable 'string' at the very least because it is easy to confuse a variable 'string' with Python's string module, though you're unlikely to be importing that any time soon.

¹[This](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-understanding-of-sine-waves/) seems like a good place to learn about sine waves